# Kotlin rxjava switchIfEmpty

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I'm trying to understand the logic of switchIfEmpty operator. I will be very thankful for every explanation.
I have a local database (Room) and remote server. My goal is to implement logic with switchIfEmpty to check if there is data in local DB to take it and if local DB is empty to call from remote. The process starts in activity where I subscribe to Observable:

```
    private fun subscribeOnDataChanges() = with(viewModel) {
        requestNextPage()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                filmsAdapter.addItems(it)
            }, {
                errorEvent.value = ERROR_MSG
                it.printStackTrace()
            }).addTo(autoDisposable)
    }
```

Then the methods in the View Model:

```
    fun requestNextPage(): Observable<List<Film>> {
        return requestPageOfFilms()
    }

    private fun requestPageOfFilms(): Observable<List<Film>> =
        interactor.requestPageOfFilmsFromDataSource()
```

And, finally the method with switchIfEmpty in the Interactor:

```
    fun requestPageOfFilmsFromDataSource(): Observable<List<Film>> {
        return repo.getPageOfFilmsInCategory(category).filter { it.isNotEmpty() }.switchIfEmpty(
            getFromRemote(category)
        )
    }

    private fun getFromRemote(category: String): Observable<List<Film>> {
        return convertSingleApiToObservableDtoList(
            retrofitService.getFilms(
                category, API.KEY, "ru-RU", NEXT_PAGE
            )
        )
    }
```

I cannot understand the next things:

1. Why, when local db (repo) is NOT empty, getFromRemote() is called?
2. If local db is empty, why network call in the method getFromRemote() is not performed? No matters, that I subscribed in the activity? Because if I add the subscription inside the switchIfEmpty(), the network call is performed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions :

> 1. Why, when local db (repo) is NOT empty, getFromRemote() is called?

Because this function `convertSingleApiToObservableDtoList()` is being evaluated at **Assembly Time** and not **Subscription Time** (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#assembly-time). The result is that the Observable object is eagerly evaluated.

> 2. If local db is empty, why network call in the method getFromRemote() is not performed? No matters, that I subscribed in the activity? Because if I add the subscription inside the switchIfEmpty(), the network call is performed.

Because the upstream has not emitted a value yet or completed.  You are conflating an empty `List` with an empty `Observable` (https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defaultifempty.html)

A better solution to your problem would be using the `flatMap` or even `switchMap` operator if you expect a chatty upstream and only care about latest result, something like :

```
fun requestPageOfFilmsFromDataSource(): Observable<List<Film>> {
    return repo.getPageOfFilmsInCategory(category)
        .flatMap { films ->
            if (films.isNotEmpty()) {
                Observable.just(films)
            } else getFromRemote(category)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I've tried your solution. It works for first page only. The second page, when local db is empty, isn't being asked from the network, even if I add a subscription to getFromRemote(category).

Comment: Well pagination not working (which has no pagination logic provided in your question) is really outside the scope of your question(s) which was to do with rxJava and `switchIfEmpty`?